# Фраза «…самых высоких в стране и благодаря…» — нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, предлоги

> Дом принадлежал к числу самых высоких в стране и благодаря своему
>   положению просматривался из любой части города.

На мой взгляд, не хватает запятой: *«Дом принадлежал к числу самых высоких в стране, и благодаря своему положению просматривался из любой части города»*.

Или, может быть, так: *«Дом принадлежал к числу самых высоких в стране и, благодаря своему положению, просматривался из любой части города»*?

Заранее благодарен за ответы.

Comment: @shampar  Исправьте, пожалуйста, обратно: точка ставится после закрывающих кавычек.

Comment: Цитата (отдельная) не может не включать все знаки цитируемой фразы. Сделаю иначе.

Comment: Вместо "дом", в этом контексте уместнее использовать слово "здание".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Второй вариант верный:

*Дом принадлежал к числу самых высоких в стране и, благодаря своему положению, просматривался из любой части города.*

Перед союзом "и" запятая не нужна, так как в предложении одна основа (одно подлежащее и два сказуемых): *Дом принадлежал и просматривался*.

Обособление оборота с "благодаря" факультативно, но в данном случае предпочтительно, так как оборот стоит между подлежащим и вторым сказуемым, а также не в начале и не в конце предложения.

См. [здесь](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/punctum-attach1).

> В спорных случаях окончательное решение о постановке знаков препинания принимает автор текста.